# Generating RSA keys for a user

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to generate an RSA key pair for a user on a multi-user remote host so that it can connect to another remote host.

When I run:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C "notes"
```

It returns: Could not create directory '/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/.ssh.

The "could not create directory" aside, this doesn't seem like the best location to be storing my private key.

Where should I be storing these files? and any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

**Update** I gave the user Sudo rights. and ran keygen via sudo -u user and still got permission denied.

It doesn't seem like I'm logged in properly. When I log in with my users credentials I get -bash-3.2$ instead of user$

Comment: `ssh-keygen` puts public and private keys in a user's `$HOME/.ssh` directory. Are you generating the key as some other user? The account you're using looks to be using a website file directory as its home.

Comment: @birryree It is. I enabled SSH for an ftp user. I do have root access. Should I be using root and su -u user ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa -C "notes"

Answer (score 2):

You should add it as sudoer in a diretory specific to the user of your choice

```
sudo -u username ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -f /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa -C "notes"
```

Cheers

Comment: `sudo -u username ssh-keygen...` actually to have the file ownerships right...

Comment: Will this still generate the keys for the correct user or will it generate them as root. Also, is this a bad location to put them?

Comment: It will generate the keys as root with permissions only for root.  So it won't work.  You need to use sudo -u username as pointed out by Kimvais.

Comment: @MattH Will it then put it in the proper location as well? I don't want it in a web user directory

Comment: I redited my answer

Comment: @svassr I'm still getting permissions errors. I've already added my user to the sudo list. For some reason its not showing me logged in as user$ its showing me as -bash-3.2$ could this be the problem?